# php reference problem

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $a = array("ABC","DEF");
    foreach($a as &$b){
        $b++; 
        echo $b . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Can any body explain me why the above code snippet generate the following output?

output:

ABD 
 
DEG

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained in [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in Perl 'Z'+1 turns into 'AA', while in C 'Z'+1 turns into '[' ( ord('Z') == 90, ord('[') == 91 ). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII characters (a-z and A-Z) are supported.

And if you mean why $b has changed:

You pass reference to $b in foreach loop, so assignments, increases etc. are done on reference to $b not on value that $b represents.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `++` on a string it is "counted up": the next char in the alphabet is used. Remove the `$b++;` and your output will be "ABC DEF"

[Good explanations here](http://technosophos.com/content/using-php-strings-unusual-ways)

*hint:
If you call `$a[0][1]`, it would return "B".*